# Posting batch request using odata4j consumer

Tags: odata, odata4j

I am planning to use `ODATA4J` libraries in our project.

As of now , I have set of records that needs to be sent to `ODATA` services. Though I could send each record individually, I am looking for options to send it in a batch using `ODATA4J`.

I could find references about producer side library (`ODataBatchProvider`). However , not able to find documentation on consumer side.

Appreciate any help in pointers/documents regarding usage of consumer (client) side library of `ODATA4J` to post batch requests.

Comment: By "record" you mean probably Entity, right? For example a Person object which is stored into OData services. Thinking about getting "batch" or set of entities on consumer side... you can (maybe?) simply use getEntities(); request. Or this does not work for your use case?

Comment: Thanks tsykora. I can get the Entities. However , I want to know how to send set of Entities in one HTTP Request to the server. The ODATA specification talks about "Batch" POST request. I am trying to find any odata4j library class that implements it. Thanks